# I have rectangular image dataset in vision transformers. I set image_size= (128, 256) but what could be the patch size,?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, typeerror, huggingface-transformers

`Any help will be greatly appreciated. I am very much confused about when i use image_size=(128, 256 ), what will be the  patch_size, if i use patch_size= 16 only i can run code upto  model training phase. Here is how i set dimensions`
--------------------------

```
#import torch.nn.functional as nnf
# Create image size
IMG_SIZE = 128, 256

# Create transform pipeline manually
manual_transforms = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((IMG_SIZE)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
])           
print (f"Manually created transforms: {manual_transforms}") 

Output: Manually created transforms: Compose (
Resize (size= (128, 256), interpolation=bilinear, max_size=None, 
antialias=warn)
ToTensor()
)
```

i am trying to use vision transformers for image classification
on custom dataset. But my dataset contains all rectangular shapes. when i use image size = 224 then accuracy is not so good, because i guess rectangular shape is reshaped into a square of 224 X 224, due to which
during training phase image features are not fully extracted. I want to input image to transformers encoder as 128 X 256 but when i set patch_siz= 16 then got an error when go for model training phase. **the runtime error is--> *****RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must
except in dimension 1.Expected size 1024 but got size 64 for
tensor number 1 in the list. *******

```
  I go errorless results when i use image size as 224X224. the issue is with rectangular shaped dimensions. I am using batch size = 16, image_size=(128, 256), patch size= 16. But is patch_size 16 is ok or it could be patch_size=(16X32) but when try to set patch_size=(16, 32) like this


import torch.nn.functional as nnf
# Create image size
IMG_SIZE =  128, 256

# Create transform pipeline manually
manual_transforms = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((IMG_SIZE)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
])           
print(f"Manually created transforms: {manual_transforms}")
--------
OUTPUT=Manually created transforms: Compose(
Resize(size=(128, 256), interpolation=bilinear, max_size=None, 
antialias=warn)
ToTensor()
)
--------
# Set the batch size
BATCH_SIZE = 16

# Create data loaders
train_dataloader, test_dataloader, class_names = 
create_dataloaders(
    train_dir=train_dir,
    test_dir=test_dir,
    transform=manual_transforms, 
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE
)

train_dataloader, test_dataloader, class_names

----------------------------------
OUTPUT:(<torch.utils.data.dataloader.DataLoader at 
0x2148d4b3700>,
 <torch.utils.data.dataloader.DataLoader at 0x2148d4b3a00>,
 ['tempered', 'genuine'])
______________________________________________

# 1. Create a class which subclasses nn.Module
class PatchEmbedding(nn.Module):
    """Turns a 2D input image into a 1D sequence learnable 
embedding vector.

    Args:
        in_channels (int): Number of color channels for the input 
images. Defaults to 3.
        patch_size (int): Size of patches to convert input image 
into. Defaults to 16.
        embedding_dim (int): Size of embedding to turn image 
into. Defaults to 768.
""" 
# 2. Initialize the class with appropriate variables
def __init__(self, 
                 in_channels:int=3,
                 patch_size:int=(16, 32),
                 embedding_dim:int=768):
        super().__init__()
    
# 3. Create a layer to turn an image into patches
self.patcher = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=in_channels,
                             out_channels=embedding_dim,
                             kernel_size=patch_size,
                             stride=patch_size,
                             padding=0)

# 4. Create a layer to flatten the patch feature maps into a 
single dimension
self.flatten = nn.Flatten(start_dim=2, # only flatten the 
feature map dimensions into a
single vector
                              end_dim=3)

# 5. Define the forward method 
def forward(self, x):
# Create assertion to check that inputs are the correct shape
image_resolution = x.shape[-1]
assert image_resolution % patch_size == 0, f"Input image size 
must be divisble by patch size,
image shape: {image_resolution}, patch size: {patch_size}"
    
# Perform the forward pass
        x_patched = self.patcher(x)
        x_flattened = self.flatten(x_patched) 
    
# 6. Make sure the output shape has the right order 
        return x_flattened.permute(0, 2, 1)
-------------------------------------------------

# Let's test it on single image
patch_size = (16, 32)

# Set seeds
def set_seeds(seed: int=42):
"""Sets random sets for torch operations.

Args:
    seed (int, optional): Random seed to set. Defaults to 42.
"""
# Set the seed for general torch operations
torch.manual_seed(seed)
# Set the seed for CUDA torch operations (ones that happen on the 
GPU)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)

set_seeds()

 # Create an instance of patch embedding layer
patchify = PatchEmbedding(in_channels=3,
                      patch_size=(16, 32), 
                      embedding_dim=768)

 # Pass a single image through
print(f"Input image shape: {image.unsqueeze(0).shape}")
patch_embedded_image = patchify(image.unsqueeze(0)) # add an 
extra batch dimension on the 0th
index, otherwise will error
print(f"Output patch embedding shape: 
{patch_embedded_image.shape}")

**here is full code blocks where error traceback is 
mentionining**

________________________________________________________________
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent 
call last)
Cell In[111], line 27
25 # Pass a single image through
26 print(f"Input image shape: {image.unsqueeze(0).shape}")
---> 27 patch_embedded_image = patchify(image.unsqueeze(0)) # add 
an extra batch dimension on
the 0th index, otherwise will error
28 print(f"Output patch embedding shape: 
{patch_embedded_image.shape}")

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1518,
in Module._wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
1516     return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # 
type: ignore[misc]
1517 else:
-> 1518     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1527,
in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
1522 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of 
the logic in
1523 # this function, and just call forward.
1524 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or 
self._forward_hooks or 
self._forward_pre_hooks
1525         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or 
_global_backward_hooks
1526         or _global_forward_hooks or 
_global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1527     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
1529 try:
1530     result = None

Cell In[107], line 32, in PatchEmbedding.forward(self, x)
29 def forward(self, x):
30     # Create assertion to check that inputs are the correct 
shape
31     image_resolution = x.shape[-1]
---> 32     assert image_resolution % patch_size == 0, f"Input 
image size must be divisble by
patch size, image shape: {image_resolution}, patch size: 
{patch_size}"
34     # Perform the forward pass
35     x_patched = self.patcher(x)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'tuple'

----------------------------------------------------------

BUt if i set patch_size=16 throghly then after this code got 
error 
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
_________________________________________________________
If i use patch_size=(16,32) then 

---------------------
import torch
from vit_pytorch import ViT

class Vit(nn.Module):
"""creates a vision transformer architecture with vit-base 
hyperparameters by default."""

def __init__(self, img_size=(128, 256), in_channels=3, 
patch_size=(16, 32), num_transformer_layers=12, 
embedding_dim=768, 
mlp_size=3072, num_classes=1000, dim=1024, depth=6, num_heads=8, 
mlp_dim=2048, mlp_dropout=0.1, embedding_dropout=0.1):
super().__init__()
self.img_size = img_size
self.in_channels=in_channels
self.patch_size = patch_size
self.num_transformer_layers = num_transformer_layers
self.embedding_dim = embedding_dim
self.mlp_size=mlp_size
self.num_classes = num_classes
self.dim =dim
self.depth = depth
self.num_heads = num_heads
self.mlp_dim = mlp_dim
self.mlp_dropout = mlp_dropout
self.embedding_dropout = embedding_dropout
    
    # calculate number of patches
height, width = img_size
patch_height, patch_width = patch_size
self.num_patches = (height // patch_height) * (width // 
patch_width)
    
    # calculate patch embedding
self.patch_embedding = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=in_channels, 
embedding_dim=enbedding_dim, patch_size=patch_size, 
stride=patch_size, bias=False)
self.patch_embedding = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=in_channels,
                                          kernel_size=patch_size,
                                          
 embedding_dim=enbedding_dim,
                                            bias=False)
    # calculate class token
    self.class_token = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1, 1, dim))
    
    # calculate positional embeddings
    self.row_embeddings = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(height // 
patch_height, 1, dim))
self.col_embeddings = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(width // 
patch_width, 1, dim))
    
    # calculate transformer blocks
    self.transformer_encoder = 









nn.ModuleList([TransformerEncoderBlock(
                                     embedding_dim=embedding_dim,
                                                                        
                                      num_heads=num_heads,
                                                                        
                                       mlp_size=mlp_size,
                                                                    
                                       mlp_dropout=mlp_dropout) 
                           for _ in range(num_transformer_layers)
])
    
    # calculate layer normalization
    self.layer_norm = nn.LayerNorm(dim)
    
    # calculate classification head
    self.classification_head = nn.Linear(dim, num_classes)
    
def forward(self, x):
    # calculate patch embeddings
    x = self.patch_embedding(x)
    x = x.flatten(2).transpose(1, 2)
    
    # calculate class token
    class_token = self.class_token.expand(x.shape[0], -1, -1)
    x = torch.cat((class_token, x), dim=1)
    
    # calculate positional embeddings
    row_embeddings = self.row_embeddings.repeat(1, x.shape[0], 1)
    col_embeddings = self.col_embeddings.repeat(1, x.shape[0], 1)
    x = x + row_embeddings + col_embeddings
    
    # calculate transformer blocks
    for transformer_block in self.transformer_encoder:
        x = transformer_block(x)
    
    # calculate layer normalization
    x = self.layer_norm(x)
    
    # calculate classification head
    class_logits = self.classification_head(x[:, 0])
    
return class_logits
_______________________________________

# Train our MOdel

# Create an instance of ViT with the number of classes we're 
working with (-,-)
vit = Vit(num_classes=len(class_names))

____________________________________________________________

from going_modular.going_modular import engine

# Setup the optimizer to optimize our ViT model parameters using 
hyperparameters from the ViT
paper 
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(params=vit.parameters(), 
                         lr=3e-3, # Base LR from Table 3 for ViT- 
* ImageNet-1k
                         betas=(0.9, 0.999), 
                         weight_decay=0.3) # from the ViT paper 
section 4.1 (Training & Fine-
                         tuning) and Table 3 for ViT-* ImageNet- 
1k

# Setup the loss function for multi-class classification
loss_fn = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# Set the seeds
set_seeds()

# Train the model and save the training results to a dictionary
results = engine.train(model=vit,
                   train_dataloader=train_dataloader,
                   test_dataloader=test_dataloader,
                   optimizer=optimizer,
                   loss_fn=loss_fn,
                   epochs=10,
                   device=device)

---------------------------------
OUT-
0%|                                                                                                                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------- 

-----------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent 
call 
last)
Cell In[132], line 16
13 set_seeds()
15 # Train the model and save the training results to a 
dictionary
---> 16 results = engine.train(model=vit,
17                        train_dataloader=train_dataloader,
18                        test_dataloader=test_dataloader,
 
19                        optimizer=optimizer,
20                        loss_fn=loss_fn,
21                        epochs=10,
22                        device=device)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\Image- 
Classification-Using-Vision-transformer- 
main\going_modular\going_modular\engine.py:169, in train(model, 
train_dataloader, test_dataloader, optimizer, loss_fn, epochs, 
device)
167 # Loop through training and testing steps for a number of 
epochs
168 for epoch in tqdm(range(epochs)):
--> 169     train_loss, train_acc = train_step(model=model,
170                                       
dataloader=train_dataloader,
171                                       loss_fn=loss_fn,
172                                       optimizer=optimizer,
173                                       device=device)
174     test_loss, test_acc = test_step(model=model,
175       dataloader=test_dataloader,
176       loss_fn=loss_fn,
177       device=device)
179     # Print out what's happening

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\Image- 
Classification-Using-Vision-transformer- 
main\going_modular\going_modular\engine.py:45, in 
 train_step(model, 
 dataloader, loss_fn, optimizer, device)
 42 X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)
 44 # 1. Forward pass
---> 45 y_pred = model(X)
 47 # 2. Calculate  and accumulate loss
 48 loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
 packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1518, in 
 Module._wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
 1516     return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # 
 type: 
 ignore[misc]
 1517 else:
-> 1518     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1527, in 
Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
1522 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of  
logic in
1523 # this function, and just call forward.
1524 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or 
self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
1525         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or 
_global_backward_hooks
1526         or _global_forward_hooks or 
_global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1527     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
1529 try:
1530     result = None

Cell In[94], line 63, in Vit.forward(self, x)
 61 # calculate class token
 62 class_token = self.class_token.expand(x.shape[0], -1, -1)
 ---> 63 x = torch.cat((class_token, x), dim=1)
 65 # calculate positional embeddings
 66 row_embeddings = self.row_embeddings.repeat(1, x.shape[0], 1)

RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 1. 
Expected size 1024 but got size 64 for tensor number 1 in the 
list.
```

Comment: I am very newcomer to this deep learning field. I tried a lot but cannot figure out what part of code i need to adjsut.  Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using ViT from module `vit_pytorch`

This is the `ViT` class definition taken from [github](https://github.com/lucidrains/vit-pytorch/blob/main/vit_pytorch/vit.py)

```
class ViT(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, *, image_size, patch_size, num_classes, dim, depth, heads, mlp_dim, pool = 'cls', channels = 3, dim_head = 64, dropout = 0., emb_dropout = 0.):
        super().__init__()
        image_height, image_width = pair(image_size)
        patch_height, patch_width = pair(patch_size)

        assert image_height % patch_height == 0 and image_width % patch_width == 0, 'Image dimensions must be divisible by the patch size.'

        num_patches = (image_height // patch_height) * (image_width // patch_width)

        # more code follows that we dont care about ...
```

and this is the definition of `pair()`

```
def pair(t):
    return t if isinstance(t, tuple) else (t, t)
```

and this is taken from the docs

> image_size: If you have rectangular images, make sure your image size is the maximum of the width and height.

> patch_size: Size of patches. image_size must be divisible by patch_size.

> The number of patches is:  n = (image_size // patch_size) ** 2 and n must be greater than 16. In your case, choose 16 (larger model) or 32 (smaller model)

As you can see, `ViT` can handle both, image_shape as tuples (first height, then width) or as a single number. The `pair` function will handle the latter case and duplicates the value into a tuple.

There is only on line of code where the `image_size` is ever used, and that is for calculating the number of tokens. This calculation is rather easy, as it only requires to divide the `image_height` by `patch_height` and `image_width` by `patch_width` and multiplying these values.

So, coming back at your problem: The docs tell a different story than the code. Reading the code, which is clear about the situation, I'd recommend to pass a tuple of `(image_height, image_width)` to the `image_size` argument of `ViT()`.

Comment: I had a look at the underlying code and edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the architecture you are using, but it is common to work with squared input images. Even though it looks strange to humans, a machine that is trained with distorted images and in inference time is fed with the same distorted images won't make a difference.

I assume your framework does not support rectangular input.

You can make the input square by padding your images with black bars. This can be easily done in your data loader.

```
# just for demonstration
rect = np.ones((128, 256, 3))  # rectangular image
square = np.zeros((256, 256, 3))  # square image
square[0:128,:,:] = rect  # fill the rect into the square
```

Of course you need to preprocess images the same way at inference.

Also, this makes the model unnecessary larger. So dont worry and use your distorted images.